# determine if image src has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, src

I have img tag that a shows the user avatar. When he pushes a button to edit the image and selects a new one, the img src on the page changes to the new image src.

How can I know when the src changes?

This is the code to the button that user presses to change the image.

```
<div style="width: 80px; height: 80px; line-height: 80px;" class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail"></div>
                                                    <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span>
```

As you can see it is not button tag.

Comment: Change the event handler bound to the button ?

Comment: @user1961671 While that might be useful it doesn't seem to be appropriate as a comment. Consider editing your original post.

Comment: There's no built-in JavaScript event handler that watches for changes to the DOM. What you should do, I think, is monitor clicks on the button instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".fileupload-new").click(function() {
  alert("check value of img src");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try checking if image is loaded:

```
$("img").bind("load", function(){
    alert("image has been loaded");
});
```